# Moving object files and dependency into a separate folder using Make

Tags: makefile

I have a series of source code directories as follows

```
main --- src1
       |-src2
       |-src3
```

My make system generates dependancy files (`*.d`) as well as object files (`*.o`).

The dependacy files are generated using the following code.

```
%.d: %.c 
    @echo calculating dependencies for $*.o
    @if $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MG -MP -MT $*.o $< -MF temp.d; then \
      echo $@ "`cat temp.d`" >$@; \
      rm temp.d; \
    else \
      rm -f temp.d; \
      rm -f $@; \
      false; \
    fi;
```

I would like to move the dependency files and object files into two separate folders `objects` and `dependency`.

They are at the same level as main folder. How do I do this using `Make` subsystem

Comment: Are your `.d` files generated as a side-effect of the compilation like with `-MD` option of `gcc` ? Or using `makedepend` ? Or as a side-effect of the compilation but with makedepend or gcc -MM in the `%.o` rule ? Or by a specific, separated, phony rule ? Tell us more.

Comment: @JulienPalard - Please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at:

http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Maybe the best is to generate dependency files as a side effect of compilation, instead of explicitly generating them in a specific rule, this way:

- You're calling `gcc` once instead of twice per target
- If the dependencies does not exists, it means than nothing has been built so everything will be built, dependencies are useless at this stage
- While building, `gcc -MMD` will generate `.d` files
- Make make include all `.d` files using a `-include` so it won't whine if they don't exists but read them if they do
- A simple `mv` can move them whenever you want right after the compilation.

So I preconize dropping your %.d: %.c rule, dropping dependencies to `.d` files, and just include all `.d` files from the dependency directory.

Also I'll avoid `if; then; else; fi`, just do a simple:

```
gcc ... -MMD ...
cp ...
```

(By putting the -MMD and other dependency related flags in a variable like `DEPFLAGS`.)

If the `gcc` fails, the `cp` won't be executed, make will just whine about `gcc` failing and exit.

Then, to move your object files, what about a simple:

```
place_where_you_want_your_obj_files/%.o: place_where_gcc_put_them/%.o
    mv $< $@
```